# In this example, which of these vectors are support vectors?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, classification, svm, kernel-trick

> The hyperplane of hard margin SVM with $\phi$ kernel is calculated as following that input space using $\phi$ to map to higher dimension space.
>
> $$f(\phi(x))=4\phi_1(x)+9\phi_2(x)+4\phi_3(x)$$
>
> $$ \phi(x)=\left[
> \begin{array}{c}
>   \phi_1(x)=x_1^2\\
>   \phi_2(x)=x_2^2\\\phi_3(x)=x_1x_2\\\phi_4(x)=-x_1
> \end{array}
> \right] $$
>
> Which of the following can be a support vector?
>
> $$ x=\left[
> \begin{array}{c}
>   +1\\
>   1
> \end{array}
> \right] $$
> $$ y=\left[
> \begin{array}{c}
>   1\\
>   -1
> \end{array}
> \right] $$
>
> Options:
>
> 1. $\ x=$ YES, $\ y=$ No
> 2. $\ x=$ YES, $\ y=$ YES

The correct answer is option $1$. My challenge is where is the trick in this question, because calculation by hand shown that none of them are support vectors? How can we choose an option here?

Comment: Can you also share how your thinking process is? i.e. why do you think that the given vectors are not SVs?

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Answer (score 1):

If (())=41()+92()+43() is the equation of the  SVM, what in

the [wikipedia entry for SVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support-vector_machine) is the formula $w^T x - b$, (or better $w^T \phi(x) - b$ after you use the kernel trick) then points in the support vector should have $f(\phi(x)) = \pm 1$ (see [this figure in the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support-vector_machine#/media/File:SVM_margin.png)).

So just plug in the values of the two points and check whether $f(\phi(x))$ and $f(\phi(y))$ is either +1 or -1.